# Plotting 3d line graph using matplotlib. TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, computer-science

This is my code :

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    with open("TestGraph.txt") as f:
        data = f.read()

    data = data.split('\n')



    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')



    x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
    y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
    z = [row.split(' ')[2] for row in data]
    ax.plot_wireframe(x, y,z)

    plt.show()
```

TestGraph.txt is

```
     1 2 3
     3 4 5
     5 6 7
     7 8 9
     9 1 8
```

When I print out x , y , z they are all the right values. I don't understand what the error means.

Comment: It's always a good idea to post the *entire* traceback in the question, not just provide the summary in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x`, `y` and `z` variables are lists of strings (`S32`). The `plot_wireframe` expects `float` (`float64`). Here's a simpler solution. You can use `pandas` too.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = r"TestGraph.txt"

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

data = np.loadtxt(f)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
z = data[:, 2]
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```